Floyd's algorithm using negative values
This code searches for the shortest paths in a graph using Floyd's algorithm. It works great for positive numbers. But when negative ones appear, it begins to make cycles and loops. How to fix it?
    for k in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if i == j:  
                    dist[i][j] = 0  
                else:
                    dist[i][j] = min(dist[i][j], dist[i][k] + dist[k][j])
    return dist

As a result, I would like to get an algorithm that will not artificially create negative cycles.

Floyd's algorithm supports negative weights. It doesn't support negative cycles because there is no shortest path when a negative cycle exists.

@interjay Rather sounds like you're talking about walks, not about paths. Or how do negative cycles prevent shortest paths?

@nocomment I haven't heard that distinction before (and for example, the Wikipedia article on Floyd-Warshall also says there is no shortest path, so apparently the distinction is not always done). But in any case, this algorithm doesn't support negative cycles.

@interjay I looked at the Path article, which says "joins a sequence of vertices which, by most definitions, are all distinct" and gives definitions for walk etc.

Modify the algorithm to detect negative cycles:
for k in range(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i ==j:
                dist[i][j] = 0
            else:
                dist[i][j] = min(dist[i][j], dist[i][k] + dist[k][j])
for k in range(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if dist[i][j] > dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]:
                print("Graph contains a negative-weight cycle")
                return None
return dist

